# Automorphisms of the exceptional Jordan algebra preserve the determinant and trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, trace, algebras

I am trying to show that the automorphism of the exceptional Jordan algebra $\mathbb{J}_3(\mathbb{O})$ preserve the determinant and trace. This algebra consists of $3x3$ Hermitian matrices over octonions:
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
a & z & \overline{y} \\
\overline{z} & b & x \\
y & \overline{x} & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with product defined by $X \circ Y = \frac12 (XY+YX)$. What I want to understand is, why does any automorphism of $\mathbb{J}_3(\mathbb{O})$ preserve $\det(X)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(X)$. I was thinking towards the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (namely, its form for the $3\times 3$ matrices):
$$
X^3 - \operatorname{tr}(X)X^2 - \frac12 (\operatorname{tr}(X^2) - \operatorname{tr}(X)^2)X - \det(X)I = 0,
$$
but I don't know what to do next. Can you please suggest anything?